# Typeerror: Metaclass conflict

Tags: python, django, django-views

I received this error via my console:
[image: console error when I try to run server]

it points out the problem to be this view:
[image: the Views]

Please how do I solve this issue?Thanks

Comment: `IsStaff` is a simple object, you can not use this to inherit, unless it is a type, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images* of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsStaff` does not make much sense as a base class, since a base class needs to have as type (its metaclass) `type`, or a subclass of `type`.

What you likely want to do is create a mixin to restrict the view, such that only staff members can access this. You can create such mixin and let it inherit from the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) and perhaps the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class IsStaffMixin(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

THe `LoginRequiredMixin` is not per se necessary. If you use the standard builtin user model, then the non-logged in users are not staff, so then it can be omitted.

In your view, you can then use the `IsStaffMixin`:

```
class SendUserEmailsView(IsStaffMixin, FormView):
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `SendUserEmailsView`, instead of <s>`SendUserEmails`</s>.